# How to connect Jenkins and aws dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-dynamodb, jenkins-plugins

I want to store values from Environment Variables of Jenkins to AWS DynamoDb. I request anyone of you could help me how to connect Jenkins and DynamoDb either using manual configuration or using Jenkins shell command.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS CLI for this, launching the command from your Jenkins pipeline code.

More info here:

[Using the AWS CLI with DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.CLI.html#Tools.CLI.UsingWithDDB)